# Querying XML satisfying two conditions with Excel VBA

Tags: xml, vba

I am building Excel VBA code to query value satisfying two conditions.

XML data is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sales>
    <Sale>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Area>NY</Area>
        <Data Date="20200401">
            <Target>110</Target>
            <Actual>80</Actual>
        </Data>
        <Data Date="20200402">
            <Target>110</Target>
            <Actual>80</Actual>
        </Data>
    </Sale>
</Sales>
```

and VBA code is like below,

```
Dim doc As Object

Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
doc.async = False: doc.validateOnParse = False
doc.Load ("C:\vb\sales.xml")

Set Nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Sales/Sale[Name='John' and /Data/@Date='20200401']/Data")

For Each Node In Nodes
     Debug.Print Node.SelectSingleNode("Actual").Text
Next Node

Set doc = Nothing
```

The code below is wrong, could you advise to fix it?

```
doc.SelectNodes("//Sales/Sale[Name='John' and /Data/@Date='20200401']/Data")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression has a little error. The path `/Data/@Date='20200401'` is absolute (relative to the document node) and not relative to the context node `Sale`.
So use

```
//Sales/Sale[Name='John' and Data/@Date='20200401']/Data
```

and you should be fine to select the `Data` element with the given properties.

Comment: Appreciate your comment. working well after deleting '/'.